# caret package classifiers are not responding

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, naivebayes

I am trying to model a train data with caret package's classifiers, but it does not respond for a very long time (I have waited for 2 hours). On the other hand, it works for other datasets.

Here is the link to my train data: http://www.htmldersleri.org/train.csv (It is well-known Reuters-21570 data set)

And the command I am using is:

```
model<-train(class~.,data=train,method="knn")
```

Note: for any other method (eg: svm, naive bayes, etc.), is stucks anyway.

Note 2: For package e1071, naiveBayes classifier works, but with 0,08% accuacy!

Can anyone tell me what can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be multiclass classification problem. I'm not sure if `caret` supports that. However, I can show you how you would do the same thing with the `mlr` package

```
library(mlr)
x <- read.csv("http://www.htmldersleri.org/train.csv")
tsk <- makeClassifTask(data = x, target = 'class')
#Assess the performane with 10-fold cross-validation
crossval('classif.knn', tsk)
```

If you want to know which learners are integrated in mlr that support this kind of task, type
    `listLearners(tsk)`

Comment: Here, "tsk" is my model, isn't it? How can I apply this model to the test data? predict() is not working...

Comment: No, `tsk` is not the model. It's the definition of the prediction task. In my example, training and testing of the model is done in one step using the function `crossval`. If you want to separate the two steps, I would recommend to read the tutorial of `mlr`: https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/